# Distances on spheres in Cayley graphs of non-amenable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, cayley-graphs

Let $G$ be a non-amenable group (or perhaps more generally, a group with exponential growth). For any $\epsilon>0$, define the *shell of radius r*, $S_\epsilon(r)$, as the set of points that lie at a distance $[r-\epsilon,r+\epsilon]$ from the identity:
$$S_\epsilon(r) = \{ g \in G \, : \, r-\epsilon \leq |g| \leq r+\epsilon\},$$
where $|g| = d(g,e)$ is the geodesic length of the element $g$.

Now regard $S_\epsilon(r)$ as a subgraph. My question is the following: **how does the largest distance between two points in $S_{\epsilon}(r)$ scale with $r$?** That is, what is the value of
$${\rm diam}(S_\epsilon(r)) \equiv \max_{u,v\in S_\epsilon(r)} d_{S_\epsilon(r)}(u,v),$$
where $d_{S_\epsilon(r)}(u,v)$ is the length of the shortest path between $u,v$ which stays entirely in $S_\epsilon(r)$? (in the case where $S_\epsilon(r)$ is disconnected, define ${\rm diam}(S_\epsilon(r)) = \infty$).

Since $G$ is assumed non-amenable, $|S_\epsilon(r)| \sim e^{\alpha r}$ grows exponentially with $r$ (here $\alpha$ is some $O(1)$ constant). This implies that ${\rm diam}(S_\epsilon(r))$ is at least linear in $r$ (**edit:** as R W points out, this fact does not rely on non-amenability). Can we say anything stronger? In particular, does ${\rm diam}(S_\epsilon(r))$ always grow exponentially with $r$? This is true if $G$ is a hyperbolic group, but I am curious if it holds more generally.

Comment: What does the fact that the diameter of spheres is at least linear have to do with growth? This is true for any infinite group.

Comment: Ah I see, what is the argument there? (probably simple but I am not seeing it immediately). Note that for me, "diameter" is defined by using the distance of paths that stay entirely within $S_\epsilon(r)$.

Comment: Take any geodesic of length $2r$ and look at the $r$ ball centered at its midpoint.